# IE8 javascript debugger

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is it possible using IE8 javascript debugger from ie8 dev tools to debug javascript on a page that runs locally from within VS2008 or you would have to run the page on a server against iis? 
Currently I am getting an error "Unable to attach to process" if I try to debug javascript on a local page.

Comment: Yes it is possible, I don't see what problem you could be having. Maybe give a description of the steps you have taken. EDIT: Why are you trying to attach to a process? Are you using the IE8 dev tools?

Comment: javascript runs in the browser, so it doesnt really have anything to do with a server. it can run from a file on your hard drive. if you are using the IE8 integrated debuger, you dont need to attach to anything just open the page and set breakpoints. if you are using VS then you need to attach to the browser process, but then dont use the intergrated IE8 debugger.

Comment: @anothershrubery - thanks for reply. Yes, that is what I am trying to run - IE8 dev tools to debug javascript on a page that I run from VS2008

Comment: Then as Menahem says, you need not attach VS to any process as you can just use the IE8 tools.

Comment: @anonshrubery - I am not trying to attach anything, it's in the error message I am getting from IE8 tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is due to the fact you most likely already have a debugger attach to the process running the web application. You will have to stop the other debugger, most likely VS, and then you will be able to attach the client JavaScript debugger.

Comment: thanks for reply. so I need to stop VS then? That would unload the page I am trying to debug:-)

Comment: true, what I do in that case when I need to debug in the client side using the Developer tools, is to stop the VS debugger and navigate to the URL using different instance of IE, not the one that lunched from when VS starts in debug mode, the URL should be available

Comment: oh yeah forgot about this little trick, thanks for reminder. It works this way fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggist IE Developer tool bar for IE

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535

it will help you debugging JavaScript just from your IE browser

also for FireFox you can use firebug

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/

Regards

and for your question i think you must be in your server to debug your staff from vs2008

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things you should do in order to debug from Visual studio.

General the below tip is the thing I always used to forget.

First enable debugging in IE: go to Tools > Internet Options > Advanced, and make sure “Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer)” is unchecked and “Display a notification about every script error” is checked.

You can more information [here](http://berniesumption.com/software/how-to-debug-javascript-in-internet-explorer/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the clear step by step explanation:

http://abhijitjana.net/2012/01/20/jscript-debugger-unable-to-attach-the-process-another-debugger-might-be-attached-to-the-process-while-application-is-running-from-visual-studio-solution/